Having problem with import collectAsStateWithLifecycle
import collectAsStateWithLifecycle not working
fun BoroughScreen(
modifier: Modifier= Modifier,

){
val viewModel: BoroughsViewModel = hiltViewModel()
val state: BoroughsUIState by viewModel.state.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()


LazyColumn(


    modifier = modifier
){
    items(state.boroughs){borough: Borough ->


        BoroughCard(name = borough.name, painter = painterResource(id = 

borough.image),
            contentDescription = borough.longName
        )

@HiltViewModel
class BoroughsViewModel constructor(
): ViewModel() {
private  val _state = MutableStateFlow(BoroughsUIState())


val state = _state.asStateFlow()

init {
    getBoroughs()
}
private fun getBoroughs() {
    viewModelScope.launch {

    }
}

}
import com.example.project2.commons.AppError
import com.example.project2.domain.model.Borough
data class BoroughsUIState(
val isLoading: Boolean = false,

val boroughs: List<Borough> = emptyList(),

val error:  AppError? = null

)
implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.7.0")

Define not working.  Not compiling?  Not acting like you think it should?  If so how is it acting and how did you expect it to act?

You use the wrong dependency, use this instead: androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-compose

If you look at the collectAsStateWithLifecycle documentation, it says:

Artifact: androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-compose

So you'll want to add that dependency:
implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-compose:2.7.0")

